# How to list in Terminal only files visible in Finder?

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, command-line, invisible-files

I know how to view hidden files in the Finder. Instead, what I'd like to do is list files in the shell/Terminal by the same criteria that the Finder uses for files that are hidden. (My objective is to collect metrics using a cronjob/launchd script that are consistent with what appears in the UI.)

This is proving to be more difficult than it sounds. Here is an example case of the ways I am aware of to hide a file from the Finder (Big Sur 11.6, Apple Silicon, APFS):

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch regular hidden invisible .dotfile
SetFile -a V invisible
chflags nohidden invisible
chflags hidden hidden
```

This requres that `SetFile` be present, which is available with Developer Tools.

The expected outcome of the command or script is one file, `regular`. All three of the other files are not visible in Finder under usual circumstances. I would like the solution to only require native tools (no Developer Tools or gnu coreutils/homebrew and the like).

So far, my approach would be to loop through all files output by `ls -lO | awk 'NR!=1 && $5!~/hidden/ { print $0 }'` (this filters out dotfiles and the `hidden` file flag), and use `GetFileInfo` (another Developer Tool installed alongside `SetFile`) to filter out the invisible attribute. However, this requires that Developer Tools be installed, which I would prefer to avoid the dependency on, and also seems awkward and excessively complicated--and likely also inefficient if there are thousands of files in a directory.

I suspect that the other options would be to manually parse the output of `xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo invisible` (more complicated but avoids the `GetFileInfo` dependency) or to use `osascript` to somehow make use of the Finder's existing logic instead of attempting to reimplement it using BSD tools.

**Edit:** Since apparently some users' `setfile` commands set the hidden flag, I added `chflags nohidden invisible` to the test case since it is entirely likely for the filesystem to contain files (created via other means) which only have the extended attribute FinderInfo flag and do not have the BSD file flag.

Comment: RE: "(My objective is to collect metrics using a cronjob/launchd script that are consistent with what appears in the UI.)" --  I'm curious as to what practical purpose this will serve?

Comment: @user3439894 https://d.pr/i/la1Xza Metrics are collected to be actionable, and inconsistent data is not actionable.

Comment: The Finder has an option ignore the visibility settings, so using something like `osascript` to have the it return the names of files it can see may not work the way you want.

Comment: @red_menace That's a good point, and you're absolutely correct -- if I smack `cmd`-`shift`-`.` and rerun `tell application "Finder" to get items of ((POSIX file "/tmp/test") as alias)`, I get all of the files as results.

Comment: If you remove the `hidden` flags, then the file is visible within the `Finder`.
( Checked before writing :) ).

Comment: @dan What OS are you using? There seems to be inconsistency at least between Big Sur and Sierra (which is quite a gap).

Comment: Using `System Events` instead of `Finder` appears to work (it also handles POSIX files).

Comment: All versions from `Yosemite` to `Monterey`. Here I tested quickly on `High Sierra` the one I use for stability and security. The more important fact is perhaps that I am using an HFS+, encrypted, case sensitive  FS ( to be able to work with it with all the ≠ MacOS versions and some Unixes ).

Comment: @dan Interesting... My filesystems are APFS, encrypted.

Comment: Maybe **`tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to return every item in the folder "/path/to/folder" where it is visible`** (or **`…whose visible = true`**) ?

Comment: @CJK On first try that looks like money... gosh I wish I knew more about writing AppleScript.

Comment: @NReilingh Money ?

Comment: @CJK Excuse my slang, lol. "Cash money", i.e. very excellent, an absolute win, exactly what I was looking for. I'd accept that as an answer if you'd care to write it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally posted as a comment on the off-chance this might produce the required result, although wasn’t able to test myself at the time.  However, the OP confirmed that, on his system *(Big Sur 11.6, Apple Sillicon, APFS)*, the following command returns the contents of a directory that matches what is visible in a *Finder* window that is opened and pointed at the directory path:

```
tell application id ("com.apple.systemevents") ¬
        to get every item in the folder named ¬
        "/path/to/folder" where it is visible
```

This returns a `list` of `file` and `folder` references that resolve much faster than *Finder* file references.  It will be even more performant if one retrieves a list of file paths instead:

```
tell application id ("com.apple.systemevents") ¬
        to get the POSIX path of every item in ¬
        folder "/path/to/folder" whose visible ¬
        is true
```

Since *System Events* accepts simple file paths in place of file references as parameters in many of its commands (e.g. **`move`**, **`delete`**, etc.), this can speed things up dramatically, and in most cases, will be infinity time quicker than *Finder* without blocking it.

Should you require an `alias list` in order to make use of commands only available through *Finder*, e.g. **`reveal`**, then<sup>†</sup>:

```
tell application id ("com.apple.systemevents") ¬
        to get every alias in the folder named ¬
        "/path/to/folder" where it is visible

tell application id ("com.apple.Finder") ¬
        to get the result as alias list
```

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> tbc</sup>